# NSFetchedResultsController isn't always update

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a "Google drive" app, every time I enter folder i have NSFetchedResultsController that fetch the entity with "parentId" parameter.

my NSFetchedResultsController wrapper:

```
class KnowledgeFetchedResultsController<T : KnowledgeBaseEntity> {

    private var controllerContex : NSManagedObjectContext? = appDelegate.coreDataContexts.managedObjectContext

    init(controllerTag: String,cacheName:String?, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor],predicate : NSPredicate? = nil){
        super.init()
        self.controllerTag = controllerTag

        let fetchRequest = T.getFetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest:  fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.controllerContex!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil , cacheName: cacheName)
        self.fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.delegate?.onFetchedResultsUpdate(tag: self.controllerTag)
    }
}
```

onFetchedResultsUpdate delegate is calling tableView.reloadData()

my ViewController:

```
class KnowledgeBaseViewController : UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

     private var knowledgeRepoController : KnowledgeRepoController?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         knowledgeRepoController = KnowledgeRepoControllerFactory.BaseItemsRepoController(parentId: self.parentId)
         knowledgeRepoController?.repoDelegate = self
         }

    func onFetchedResultsUpdate( tag: String) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = ...// get object
        if item?.entityType != KnowledgeType.folder {
            return
        }
        let controller = UIStoryboard.knowledgeBaseController(parentId: item?.id)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

My contexts:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? =
    {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.store?.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        managedObjectContext.stalenessInterval = 0
        return managedObjectContext
}()

func contextDidSaveContext(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let sender = notification.object as? NSManagedObjectContext {
        if sender === self.managedObjectContext {
            self.backgroundContext?.perform {
                self.backgroundContext?.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
            }
        } else if sender === self.backgroundContext {
            self.managedObjectContext?.perform {
                self.managedObjectContext?.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
            }
        } else {
            self.backgroundContext?.perform {
                self.backgroundContext?.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
            }
            self.managedObjectContext?.perform {
                self.managedObjectContext?.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the first view controller all work well, *controllerDidChangeContent* is calling, and everything is updated.

But! when I enter the second view controller the NSFetchedResultsController does not update *controllerDidChangeContent*  isn't call.

I'm don't know how to fix it, I try every answer in the internet